# Подтверждение регистрации по почте

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте! Проблема такая: я делаю регистрацию пользователей с подтверждением регистрации по почте, в таблице user имеются два поля: confirm_email типа boolean(подтвердил ли пользователь регистрацию или нет, по умолчанию false) и поле token_confirm типа string(в нем создаётся рандомный ключ), так вот, после регистрации на почту приходит письмо с ссылкой на подтверждение вида: http://localhost:3000/email_verified?token_confirm=e44b1e429b4211bc265f2e3d87db80b5b65f0a74
    Но после того, как я нажимаю на данную ссылку поле confirm_email не становится true, вот код:

```
**users_controller.rb**

    def email_verified
      @user = User.find_by_token_confirm(params[:token_confirm])
      @user.confirm_email = true
      @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email has been verified."
  end
```

ps: через консоль(rails c) к примеру

```
User.find(1).confirm_email = true
```

тоже не присваивается, так и остаётся false, данную колонку создавал так:

```
def change
    add_column :users, :confirm_email, :boolean, default: false
  end
```

true присваивается только, если присвоить true вот в этом месте в контроллере users:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
        @user.confirm_email = true
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [`update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute):

```
**users_controller.rb**

def email_verified
  @user = User.find_by_token_confirm(params[:token_confirm])
  @user.update_attribute(:confirm_email, true)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email has been verified."
  else
    redirect_to root_url, flash[:error] => "Email has NOT been verified."
  end
end
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!=)